# How can animation be added to markers in "react-google-maps"?

Tags: reactjs

The docs - https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/tree/v5.1.0#documentation - say that "animation" can be added to markers.  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to add the animation.  There are also other properties I tried to add, but I was not able to.  Code snippet is posted below:

```
const ProvidenceMap = withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={13}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 41.8240, lng: -71.4128 }}
  >

    {props.markers.map((marker, index) => (
      <Marker
        key={index}
        position={marker.position}
        onClick={() => props.onMarkerClick(marker)}
        animation={marker.animation}
      >

        {marker.showInfo && (
          <InfoWindow onCloseClick={() => props.onMarkerClose(marker)}>
            {
              <div className="info-window">this is the info window</div>
            }
          </InfoWindow>
        )}
      </Marker>
    ))};
  </GoogleMap>
));

class ContentContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      landing: true,
      map: false,
      wishListTitle: "",
      markers: [
        {
          position: {lat: 41.8240, lng:-71.4128},
          showInfo: false,
          animation: "DROP",
        },
        {
          position: {lat: 41.8250, lng: -71.4338},
          showInfo: false,
          animation: "DROP",
        }
      ],
    }
  }
  /* click handlers and render() have been omitted for simplicity */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part of the README that mentions the `animation` prop refers you to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker) for the google.maps.Marker class. That documentation gives the method signature for `setAnimation` as:

> `setAnimation(animation:Animation)`

...which tells you that the type of the `animation` argument—and, presumably, the React `animation` prop—should be Animation. If you click on the link, it takes you to [Animation constants](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Animation), where you learn that two constants are defined on `google.maps.Animation`: `BOUNCE` and `DROP`.

That tells you that the value for this prop should be either `google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE` or `google.maps.Animation.DROP`. And so:

```
[
  {
    position: {lat: 41.8240, lng:-71.4128},
    showInfo: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  },
  {
    position: {lat: 41.8250, lng: -71.4338},
    showInfo: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  }
],
```

This matches what you can see in the react-google-maps examples, where [other `google.maps.*` constants are used](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/fc9617a15191d16553e9420b808412cae4b0fba4/src/app/pages/drawing/DrawingExample.js#L31-L37).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! But, I am now getting an error that says "'google' is not defined".  Should I be importing something in addition to the following? { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow, Animation, }

Comment: If you're loading the Google Maps JavaScript API [as described in the README](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/tree/v5.1.0#loading-libraries), (and it's loaded before the code in question runs), `google` should exist in the browser's global scope. If it doesn't I'm not sure why that would be.

Comment: Just figured it out!  I had to include /*global google*/ at the top of my js file in addition to synchronously loading the API in the head of my html.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When using the 'google-maps-react' component from NPM, I was able to enable animations by adding this.props before google.maps.Animation.DROP on the marker tag.  Specifically:

```
<Marker
  animation= {this.props.google.maps.Animation.DROP}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding animation on the `<Marker />` is easy. Just add `defaultAnimation` props on your `<Marker />`s like this:

```
<Marker
  ...
  defaultAnimation={google.maps.Animation.DROP}
>
</Marker>
```

and it should work just fine.